angular 18 two way data binding
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'textarea'
component.html
<textarea rows="6" [(ngModel)]="enteredValue"></textarea>
<button (click)="onSavePost()">save</button>
<p>{{ newPost }}</p>

component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-create',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './post-create.component.html',
  styleUrl: './post-create.component.css'
})
export class PostCreateComponent {
newPost="NO content Here";
enteredValue='';
onSavePost(){
  this.newPost = this.enteredValue;
}
}

app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { PostCreateComponent } from './post/post-create/post-create.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet,FormsModule,PostCreateComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Project_ng_demo';
}

here is not app.module.ts file in agnular 18
import FormsModule in app.component.ts.
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

Child components do not automatically get imports from parent components. You need to import FormsModule in PostCreateComponent as well

Posting the answer for future users' reference

Issue is that when using standalone components, children components do not automatically get imports from parents thus PostCreateComponent needs to import the FormsModule as well.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-create',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  templateUrl: './post-create.component.html',
  styleUrl: './post-create.component.css'
})
export class PostCreateComponent {
newPost="NO content Here";
enteredValue='';
onSavePost(){
  this.newPost = this.enteredValue;
}
}

